# Sub graph of the project graph in intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, multi-project

Say, for example, we have the following situation:

```
ProjectA
   |
   |
   ->ProjectB
   |    |
   |    |
   |    -> ProjectC
   |
   |-> ProjectD


ProjectY
   |
   |
   ->ProjectZ
   |    |
   |    |
   |    -> ProjectC
   |
   |-> ProjectD
```

So we have a couple of graphs of top-level modules and their dependencies, some of which are shared.

We ideally need one sbt project somewhere to encapsulate all state that a change to `D` could break.

We also, ideally, need to be able to use intellij to examine *subgraphs* only. Because these can be very large, it will be cumbersome to load the entire structure just to work in `B` on a non-breaking change. We'd like to leave the final verification that we haven't broken anything to a later stage, rather than at a development stage.

So for this requirement, we'd need to be able to load the following in intellij:

```
ProjectB
   |
   |
   -> ProjectC
```

Is there any way to achieve this with intellij and SBT? I know you can achieve it in SBT by using `sbt ProjectB/compile`, but Intellij would still load every module and therefore be unbearably slow.

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't exactly fit what you want, but IntelliJ allows you to unload specific modules. This will avoid the overhead in analyzing its contents if you are not working with them directly.

To do this, right click on a module and select "Load/Unload modules":

[image: unload module]